# Can I get Android OS?

Tags: android, operating-system, touchpad

I bought a umpc on ebay, A Ipad touchscreen like device. I had been looking at a particular hardware model that many sellers had, on which was running Android (1.6). I based my choice on the one that offered "free" shipping via UPS (3-5 day) delivery. after the purchase I noticed that the one I bought has Windows CE, not android (!*#$*^%!!!). Now I want to know if I can get a copy of Android 1.6 or higher and put it on this device. I have looked on google, Torrent sites and ebay, but cannot find a copy of Android OS

Comment: @Tiberiu I agree although I have a feeling there is going to be some substantial programming involved in getting to work ;-)

Comment: Trust me, there is no easy download-and-install option for unsupported hardware. If you've never done something similar (like compile your own Linux kernel) I wouldn't recommend trying this.

I'd try to get a refund.

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://source.android.com for instructions for downloading and building the source.  AFAIK there is no way to download the binary of the source.  It is open source and free although that's not to say that the vendor didn't have to hack it hardcore to make it work on the device.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the source for OS of Android i.e. Linux kernel is not included in the default download. You need to download them seprately from the Linux tree,

[link text](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=kernel/msm.git;a=summary)

Select from the different flavors from the bottom, for example I used the “android-msm-2.6.29-donut” source code. You can get a snapshot of entire head, which is easier than getting it via git. Then you can compile via standard Linux make procedure.